# Question regarding path independence of line integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, line-integrals

I have a fundamental question regarding path independence that should help me to better connect the dots from multivariable calculus to vector calculus.

Given some arbitrary curve $C$ and function $f(x,y,z)=(g(x,y,z),0,0)$ where $g: \mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$. If I want to evaluate the line Integral $\mathop{\int}\limits_{C} f \,d(x,y,z)$, could I directly conclude that the integral has to be path dependent. From a purely geometric interpretation, I would assume it is impossible to have path independence. Further, I believe we could not find $\varphi$ such that $f=grad$ $\varphi$ simply because $f$ has only one non zero component.

Please correct me if I am wrong. I would appreciate any help in order to get a better grasp on how to geometrically interpret this situation.

Comment: What is $(f,0,0)d(x,y)$ supposed to mean? Is that supposed to be something like $\boldsymbol{F} \cdot d \boldsymbol{r}$? Also, if $f$ is a constant or $f = f(x)$ then the curl of the vector vanishes as well. And shouldn't there be a third coordinate somewhere?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: It is still not clear. I can see now that $f$ is a _vector valued function_. But what is the measure $d(x, y, z)$ supposed to mean? Is it the same as $dx dy dz$? Or is it $(dx, dy, dz)$? If it is the former, does that mean you are integrating componentwise? If it is the latter, then the integrand doesn't make sense unless you are taking the dot product. We can't move forward until you address these issues with your question.

Comment: It is supposed to be the latter - meaning I want to take the dot product with regards to some parameterization of $C$.

Comment: Then no, you can't conclude that the integral must be path dependent, unless you insist that $g$ is functionally dependent on $y$ and $z$. The _vector field_ $f = (g, 0, 0)$ will have zero curl if it is independent of the $y$ and $z$ coordinates so that $g(x,y,z) = h(x)$, and if your domain is simply connected then you can then write $f = \nabla \phi$ which implies \begin{align} \int_{C} f \cdot (dx, dy, dz) &= \int_{C} \nabla \phi \cdot (dx, dy, dz) \\ &= \int_{C} d \phi \\ &= \phi \lvert_{C} \end{align} i.e $f$ is path independent

Answer (score 1):

The condition of grad(phi) comes from exact differential,that is if f=Mdx+Ndy and if del(M)/del(y)=del(N)/del(x),only then f can be written as a gradient fuction,so check that first.